# How to define ShapeDrawables programmatically?

Tags: java, android, xml, gradient

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape android:shape="ring" android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:thicknessRatio="8" android:useLevel="false">
            <gradient android:type="sweep" android:useLevel="false"
            android:startColor="#4c737373" android:centerColor="#4c737373"
            android:centerY="0.50" android:endColor="#ffffd300" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <rotate 
            android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" android:fromDegrees="0"
            android:toDegrees="360">
            <shape android:shape="ring" android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
            android:thicknessRatio="8" android:useLevel="false">
                <size android:width="48dip" android:height="48dip" />
                <gradient android:type="sweep" android:useLevel="false"
                android:startColor="#4c737373" android:centerColor="#4c737373"
                android:centerY="0.50" android:endColor="#ffffd300" />
            </shape>
        </rotate> 
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

How do I convert this code to Java?

Right now indicator color is blue but I want blue in first rotate after color should be green third time rotate color should red above code display only one color for all. I think I can dynamically add more color.

Comment: that won't be easy, I suggest if somehow you can manage it in xml, then prefer it

Comment: see LayerDrawable and GradientDrawable

Comment: Ok but how I gave multipal color in gradient ???